# How to compute a check digit for a large number in R?

Tags: r, division, coercion

I must add a 2-digit check (remaining of division by 97) to numbers such as 52/200005/0001 (slashes must be ignored).

My code is the following, but it fails because of too big number:

```
AppendCheckDigits <- function (x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x) & length(x) == 1 & nchar(x) == 14)
  cd <- as.integer(paste(substring(x, 1, 2),
                         substring(x, 4, 9),
                         substring(x, 11, 14), sep="")) %% 97
  paste(x, "/", cd, sep="")
}
```

Test it with:

```
AppendCheckDigits("52/200005/0001")
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects of class `integer` are restricted to about 2*10^9. You should use `as.numeric` instead of `as.integer` in your function :

```
AppendCheckDigits <- function (x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x) & length(x) == 1 & nchar(x) == 14)
  cd <- as.numeric(paste(substring(x, 1, 2),
                         substring(x, 4, 9),
                         substring(x, 11, 14), sep="")) %% 97
  paste(x, "/", cd, sep="")
}
```

Then :

```
> AppendCheckDigits("52/200005/0001")
[1] "52/200005/0001/43"
```

Note that you could vectorize and simplify your function this way, for example :

```
AppendCheckDigits <- function (x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x) & nchar(x) == rep(14,length(x)))
  num <- as.numeric(gsub("/","", x)) %% 97
  return(paste0(x, "/", num))
}
```

Then :

```
> AppendCheckDigits(c("52/200005/0001", "52/200005/0021"))
[1] "52/200005/0001/43" "52/200005/0021/63"
```

Comment: What else can I say than "I did not expect such a perfect answer, clear and extensive"?  Dunno! ;-)

Comment: The code AppendCheckDigits <- function (x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x) & nchar(x) == 14)
  num <- as.numeric(gsub("/","", x)) %% 97
  paste0(x, "/", num) seems to work in the same way as yours. Here, no "rep" and no "return". Are they really important?
}

Comment: @user3341592 No, you're right, with the recycling rule there is no need to use `rep` here. Your code is fine and cleaner.

Comment: @user3341592 You can omit it, as by default R will return the last value of a function.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on @juba's answer using file path and subbing all non digits:

```
AppendCheckDigits <- function (x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x) & nchar(x) == rep(14,length(x)))
  num <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D","", x)) %% 97
  file.path(x, num)
}

AppendCheckDigits(c("52/200005/0001", "52/200005/0021"))
## [1] "52/200005/0001/43" "52/200005/0021/63"
```

More for different ways this could be approached if a future searcher had a similar problem, this may give alternatives.

Comment: Yes, it's very nice of you to put alternatives here. Such responses are read and read, and prove to be useful!